# Migration of wordpress database from mariadb 10.0.20 to 5.5.50

Tags: mysql

I have been struggling with this one and cannot find an answer. I am not an expert with databases and had an issue that is a pain.

I am attempting to migrate a wordpress database to a different server host. The current MariaDB version is 10.0.20 and the new one is 5.5.50

I used phpmyadmin to dump the database I imported it to the new host and got this issue.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21190523/phpmysql-error-1273-1273-unknown-collation-utf8mb4-general-ci

I resolved by following the sollution to use MYSQL40

Then trying again I got an issue with TYPE=INNODB.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620439/syntax-error-when-running-a-mysql-create-table-statement

Found the solution and changed TYPE=INNODB to ENGINE=InnoDB in the dump.

Now I get this error and I have no idea how to resolve and found nothing useful

```
Warning in ./libraries/dbi/DBIMysqli.php#252
 Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=2622

Backtrace

./libraries/dbi/DBIMysqli.php#252: mysqli_query(
object,
string 'SHOW SESSION VARIABLES LIKE \'FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS\';',
integer 0,
)
./libraries/DatabaseInterface.php#240: PMA\libraries\dbi\DBIMysqli->realQuery(
string 'SHOW SESSION VARIABLES LIKE \'FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS\';',
object,
integer 1,
)
./libraries/DatabaseInterface.php#1586: PMA\libraries\DatabaseInterface->tryQuery(
string 'SHOW SESSION VARIABLES LIKE \'FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS\';',
object,
integer 1,
boolean false,
)
./libraries/DatabaseInterface.php#1380: PMA\libraries\DatabaseInterface->fetchValue(
string 'SHOW SESSION VARIABLES LIKE \'FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS\';',
integer 0,
integer 1,
object,
)
./libraries/DatabaseInterface.php#1400: PMA\libraries\DatabaseInterface->getVariable(
string 'FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS',
integer 1,
object,
)
./libraries/Util.php#3328: PMA\libraries\DatabaseInterface->setVariable(
string 'FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS',
string 'ON',
)
./import.php#636: PMA\libraries\Util::handleDisableFKCheckCleanup(boolean true)
```

Hopefully someone might have a suggestion. Thank you

Comment: try to load the dump without these lines with `SHOW SESSION ...`

Comment: just errase them of the dump file

Comment: I have found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429655/can-you-automatically-create-a-mysqldump-file-that-doesnt-enforce-foreign-key-c But even that is not working. For some reason even though I can telling the import to not check  FOREIGN KEYS it still does anyway

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a Foreign Key issue.

When you use PHPMyAdmin to create the sql dump, try using the custom settings to disable Foreign Key checks.

Comment: Thanks..Very odd. I have disabled foreign key checks when creating the dump and disabled when importing but in the error it states that's its on.